# Error in KeyConditionExpression when using contains on partition key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have `Tags` as partition key in my table, and when I am trying to query I am getting `AttributeError`.

Below is my code:

```python
kb_table = boto3.resource('dynamodb').Table('table_name')
result = kb_table.query(
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('Tags').contains('search term')
    )

return result['Items']
```

Error:

> "errorMessage": "'Key' object has no attribute 'contains'"

Basically I want to search through the table where I the field is having that search term. I have achived it using `scan` but I have read everywhere that we should not use that.

```python
result = kb_table.scan(
        FilterExpression="contains (Tags, :titleVal)", 
        ExpressionAttributeValues={ ":titleVal": "search term" }
    )
```

So I have changed my partition-key to `Tags` along with a sort-key so that I can achieve this using `query` but now I am getting this error.
Any idea how to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use [Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) you must specify one partition to access, you cannot wildcard a partition or specify multiple keys.

> KeyConditionExpression
>
> The condition that specifies the key value(s)
>   for items to be retrieved by the Query action.
>
> The condition must perform an equality test on a single partition key
>   value.

Assuming you want to search the whole table for tags, a scan is the most appropriate approach.

EDIT: You can use Query with the **exact** search term, but im guessing that is not what you want.

```
kb_table = boto3.resource('dynamodb').Table('table_name')
result = kb_table.query(
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('Tags').eq('search term')
    )

return result['Items']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes  **exact** search term cannot fulfill the purpose here, and in the `query()` i am specifying `partition key` only named **Tags**.